# Prove that this transformation inverse exists and it's bounded

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

If $X,Y$ are Normed Vectorial Spaces, $T$ is a bounded lineal transformation.
Prove that if exists $b>0$ such that $\|Tx\|\geq b\|x\| \forall x\in X$. Then $T^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ exists and it's bounded.

I've got 5 problems like this and I've never been good with proofs that start with "let $b>0$". Can you give an idea how to do this?

Comment: It should be easy to see that $T$ is $1-1$.

Answer (score 0):

An example in front: Let $T:X\hookrightarrow Y$ be the inclusion map, for
$X$ a proper subspace of $Y$.

Answer: An inverse exists and is bounded when restricting attention to the subspace $\operatorname{Im}T\subset Y$.

Assume $Tx=0$, then the norm estimate implies $x=0$, hence
$\ker T = \{0\}$. Thus $T$ defines a linear bijection from $T$ onto $\operatorname{Im}T$. 
Its inverse is bounded because for every
$y\in\operatorname{Im}T\:\Longleftrightarrow y=Tx$ one deduces
$$
\|T^{-1}y\|\:\leq\:\frac{1}{b}\|y\|
$$

Comment: If you use \ker and \operatorname{Im}, then proper spacing results in expressions like $a\ker b$ and $a\ker(b)$ (Note that the spacing to the right of $\ker$ is different in those two examples) rather than needing to be put in by hand, as in a\text{ ker } b. I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  This is good to know for future posting—thanx for commenting your edit thus ramping up my LaTeX fluency.

Comment: Glad it helps! $\qquad$